# Predicting stellar evolution and life cycle of a star

Tags: stars, stellar-physics, stellar-evolution

Is there a way to model/predict the evolution and life cycle of a star based on certain initial conditions?  That is, whether it will become a red giant, brown dwarf, etc. I'm basically looking for equations defining the progress of different star-types and how varying initial conditions may affect that progress.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25869/stellar-evolution-simulation-engine-or-software

Comment: Please check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_evolution and see if it answers your question(s).  If you still have gaps you should edit your question to make it more specific about what exactly you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at tools like [EZ-web](http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~townsend/static.php?ref=ez-web) or interpolation formulae like those from [Hurley, Pols and Tout 2000](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000MNRAS.315..543H) to do so based on the initial mass and metallicity of your star. Here is a picture of the evolution of an initial 10 solar masses star and solar metallicity computed using Hurley's formulae (accessible as a fortran library, see [this page](http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/~jhurley/stellar.html) for a web-interface)

[image: a 10 solar masses star evolution within the HR diagram]
<sub>(source: [rubyforge.org](http://sciyag.rubyforge.org/ctioga/gallery/diagramme_HR_temps.png))</sub>  !

This one compares EZ results and Hurley's formulae.

[image: EZ and Hursley's formulae comparison]