# How to calculate the life expectancy / fusion rateof a star?

Tags: astrophysics, fusion

If I have the mass (and if needed, the atomic mixture) of a star before it forms, is there some mathematical way to calculate how fast the star will burn through its contents and die?

Comment: Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_evolution the last sections states: "A stellar evolutionary model is a mathematical model that can be used to compute the evolutionary phases of a star from its formation until it becomes a remnant ....." and look at the references.

Comment: See also [Stellar evolution simulation engine or software](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25869)